# What happened to my comment?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I commented on the top answer (by KutuluMike) for this question two days ago.

[Why is the movie called "8 mile"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57625/why-is-the-movie-called-8-mile)

The answer as was written had incomplete/misleading information about the naming of 8 mile road. Part of the misleading information has been edited in the answer, but my comment elaborated on the context of the name 8 mile road--this has not been incorporated in the answer. I'm sure that nothing I said could have been interpreted as even remotely inflammatory, or off topic. So why was my comment deleted? And why does all evidence of it having existed seem to disappear from my account?

Answer (score 8):

[Comments are transitory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180298/165776) by nature. They are expected to be acted on and deleted -- that's their purpose. You should never leave a comment that includes information you want to "stick around".

The part of your comment that explained how my answer was misleading, I considered a useful change, so I made it. (You could also have submitted an edit to that effect, it would probably have been approved.) The other portion of your comment contained information that, while interesting, I found irrelevant to the answer, so I left it out.

It's not uncommon for people reading "obsolete" comments to flag them as such, and moderators will just delete them.

If you think the other information you provided is actually relevant to the question, the best place to put it would be as an answer all by itself.

Comment: Because my entire comment wasn't incorporated though, it wasn't obsolete. The context I provided on why 8 mile road is called 8 mile road isn't directly an answer to the question, but it is nonetheless relevant. So in this case I'm just beholden to whoever (in my judgement, incorrectly) decides it's obsolete and all trace of the comment disappears?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. That's how comments work. They are disposable.

Comment: @spacetyper ... you're entitled to suggest edits for questions and answers - which may be accepted or rejected by the post writer or other high-rep users.  Also if you're very enthusiastic about one answer having this information - I'd encourage you to write your own answer to the question.  That's how the site works - it doesn't matter that a number of answers have similar information, your's might be the only one that has the snippet about the name of the road and (if people value that) eventually be the highest voted answer.